# Null session pipes example, write access

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, named-pipes

I'm looking for a simple example of how to create a null session pipe, that can be read from or written to by clients on another PC through lan.

I've found this MSDN [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/813414/how-to-create-an-anonymous-pipe-that-gives-access-to-everyone), but the code there only provides read access to the pipe. I've tried to make it work for writing: changing `PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND` to `PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX` (`CreateNamedPipe` argument), `FILE_GENERIC_READ` to `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE` (`AddAccessAllowedAce` argument), and `GENERIC_READ` to `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE` (`CreateFile` argument), but I'm getting an ACCESS_DENIED (5) error when trying to call `CreateFile` in the client program. Though opening a pipe only for reading works correctly.

The server is launched on Windows 7 machine and the client on Windows XP.

Here is my Windows 7 registry key (`NullSessionPipes` contains testpipe and  AnonymousPipe strings). Maybe something there causes the problem?

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters]
"ServiceDll"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,\
  00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,\
  73,00,72,00,76,00,73,00,76,00,63,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
"ServiceDllUnloadOnStop"=dword:00000001
"EnableAuthenticateUserSharing"=dword:00000001
"NullSessionPipes"=hex(7):74,00,65,00,73,00,74,00,70,00,69,00,70,00,65,00,00,\
  00,41,00,6e,00,6f,00,6e,00,79,00,6d,00,6f,00,75,00,73,00,50,00,69,00,70,00,\
  65,00,00,00,00,00
"autodisconnect"=dword:0000000f
"enableforcedlogoff"=dword:00000001
"enablesecuritysignature"=dword:00000000
"requiresecuritysignature"=dword:00000000
"restrictnullsessaccess"=dword:00000000
"Lmannounce"=dword:00000000
"Size"=dword:00000001
"AdjustedNullSessionPipes"=dword:00000003
"Guid"=hex:eb,c5,75,fd,46,51,ce,4c,8f,64,a9,70,12,f6,05,6e
```

Could you give me the correct null session pipe example, or tell me how to edit the MSDN example?

**Update**

Here is what I've already tried:

1. `FILE_GENERIC_READ | FILE_WRITE_DATA` in both `AddAccessAllowedAce` and `CreateFile` as @HarryJohnston suggested
2. `GENERIC_ALL` in `AddAccessAllowedAce`
3. Null DACL: `SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(sa.lpSecurityDescriptor, TRUE, NULL, FALSE)`

But I haven't managed to open a pipe for writing. (ACCESS_DENIED error). pipesec.exe shows that all necessary permissions are present: "Write Data" in case of `FILE_GENERIC_READ | FILE_WRITE_DATA` and additionally "Write Attributes" and "Write Extended attributes" in case of `GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE`.

When I launch the server on XP and client on Windows 7 I get no errors.

**Update 2**

When I either enable "Network access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users" setting, or grant "Impersonate a client after authentication" user right to the ANONYMOUS LOGON group, I get no errors. This is strange because impersonation functions are not used anywhere in the MSDN example.

Comment: This is a bit of a long shot, but try `FILE_GENERIC_READ | FILE_WRITE_DATA` instead of `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE` in both AddAccessAllowedAce and in CreateFile.

Comment: @HarryJohnston thank you for your comment, but that does not fix the problem. See my update.